# Easy way to get data inside nested struct

Tags: go, struct

I have a struct that looks like this:

```
&main.INI{
  Properties: []*main.Property{
    &main.Property{
      Key: "a",
      Value: &main.Value{
        String: &"a",
      },
    },
    &main.Property{
      Key: "b",
      Value: &main.Value{
        Number: &123,
      },
    },
  },
  Sections: []*main.Section{
    &main.Section{
      Identifier: "numbers",
      Properties: []*main.Property{
        &main.Property{
          Key: "a",
          Value: &main.Value{
            Number: &10.3,
          },
        },
        &main.Property{
          Key: "b",
          Value: &main.Value{
            Number: &20,
          },
        },
      },
    },
    &main.Section{
      Identifier: "strings",
      Properties: []*main.Property{
        &main.Property{
          Key: "a",
          Value: &main.Value{
            String: &"\"quoted\"",
          },
        },
        &main.Property{
          Key: "b",
          Value: &main.Value{
            String: &"b",
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
}
```

Which is the AST of the following source code:

```
a = "a"
b = 123

# A comment
[numbers]
a = 10.3
b = 20

; Another comment
[strings]
a = "\"quoted\""
```

And I would like to know if would be possible to get all keys inside `sections -> properties -> key`

Without having to create 2 loops:

```
var keys []string
for _, section := range ini.Sections {
    for _, property := range section.Properties {
        keys = append(keys, property.Key)
    }
}
```

I'm also working in another program that generates an AST that requires 3 nested loops to get a specific property. Is there a better way to do it? A package or something?

I found `go-funk`, that provides a `.Get` method:

```
funk.Get(ini, "Sections.Properties.Key").([]string)
```

But it's not maintained.

Thank you.

Comment: You could write your own recursive function so you only have to *write* one loop, but at the end of the day you still have to iterate over both levels of the tree, which means two loops.

Comment: go-funk doesn't look unmaintained to me. There were PRs merged about 8 weeks ago. Development did quiet down, but it looks more like the package is simply done, not abandoned. It has no reason to change unless Go changes.

Comment: @Peter yes, but still, is not highly adopted by other packages, which means is not accepted by the community - right?

Comment: It just means that not everyone finds it useful (I also prefer writing two loops over adding a dependency). If it's useful to you I don't see anything that speaks against it per se.